# Archimedes' lever and the concept of work

Tags: physics, ancient-greece, classical-mechanics, archimedes

Do I understand correctly that Archimedes was not familiar with the concept of work and hence attributed mechanical advantage to a lever's ability to create force rather than understanding that the long arm of a lever might help you lift a heavy stone, but this was at the expense of the long arm having to move a longer distance than the shorter arm? (like in the attached image)

[image]

Comment: This can be quite well understood from what we now call torque. The concepts of work and energy did not appear until the second half of the second millenia.